# Using PetaPoco with webservices

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, petapoco

Where the webservice returns a DataTable, is it even possible?

All the samples reference a db/Connection object.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: As @Gareth has pointed out you need to use POCO's to get the full use of PetaPoco. Basically each POCO is just a class structured exactly like your table columns. You then execute some Sql and PetaPoco will map the results to a enumerable set of POCO's. You can just return this in your web service call and WCF will handle the rest.

Comment: In the webservice implementation use petapoco to transform the sybase data into pocos and then return the pocos to your the webservice consumers.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to return a DataTable, that's ADO.NET thinking. Instead you can return a list of pocos (classes that represent your data). Here's an example from the main [Petapoco help page at Topten Software](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) :

```
// Create a PetaPoco database object
var db=new PetaPoco.Database("connectionStringName");

// Show all articles    
foreach (var a in db.Query<article>("SELECT * FROM articles"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", a.article_id, a.title);
}
```

In this example "article" is a plain c# object like this :

```
public class article
{
    public long article_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
    public bool draft { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As for returning this from a webservice; it's nothing to do with Petapoco. It's given you a List<article> you could serialize it to xml and return it if you like, or use JavascriptSerializer and return json.

Comment: Came here to say exactly this - great answer Gareth. Returning IEnumerable<Article> and/or List<Article> should suffice. WCF will return serialize and return this in whatever format your endpoint/contract is setup for.

Comment: This would require defining poco's at the webservice level and serializing them or perhaps setting setting up an odata service or perhaps use the upcoming asp.net data api,s whereas the goal is to keep the webservice lightweight ( change free) and return the datatable which is then poco'fied on the client ! not the ideal but the db is sybase ( last i checked, poco did not work with it), there are way too many different types of queries & the dataset is quite large with 800+ columns in a dozen+ tables not to want to figure out a common schema and revert to a take only what you need approach